# How to set skipframes callsite on a NLogViewerTarget for Sentinel log viewer

Tags: c#, nlog, viewer

I have

```
var sentinalTarget = new NLogViewerTarget()
{
    Name = "sentinal",
    Address = "udp://127.0.0.1:9999",
    IncludeCallSite = true,
    IncludeSourceInfo = true
};

sentinalTarget.Parameters.Add(new NLogViewerParameterInfo() 
{   
    Name = "Callsite", 
    Layout = "${callsite:fileName=true:includeSourcePath=false:skipFrames=1}" 
});

var sentinalRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, sentinalTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("sentinal", sentinalTarget);
LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(sentinalRule);
```

I need to add `skipframe=1` on callsite in order to see the actual class that called the NLog methods.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: is the `skipframe=1` really needed? Can't you use `LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(..)` ?

Comment: It could be done, but needs some code and config

Comment: thank you Julian.
it seems that AddHideenAssembly does the trick.
also found that: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16366655/can-nlog-preserve-callsite-information-through-c-sharp-extension-methods)

Comment: I like answered questions, so added it as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

As confirmed, `LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(..)` works in this case:

Example:

`LogManager.AddHiddenAssembly(typeof(LoggingExtensions).Assembly);`

Call this method as soon as possible, e.g in `main()` or `app_start()`