# Wrapping NLog and StackTrace information

Tags: logging, ninject, wrapper, stack-trace, nlog

If you wrap NLog in another class all your stacktrace information points to the wrapper class instead of the correct place in the stack that you are interested in. How do you solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nlog Callsite information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132759/nlog-callsite-information)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass wrapper's type to the Logger.Log() method. Please, look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486163/438760